Order of tokens in Uniswap V3 pool price
I am trying to get a token price from the Uniswap V3 pool. The Uniswap V3 contract provides a slot0 field where the rate is written in two ways. (documentation)
using sqrtPriceX96 and using tick
Then it is necessary to format the value according to the decimals of both tokens.
The last thing to understand is what order of tokens corresponds to the rate.
According to the documentation:

sqrtPriceX96 is the current price of the pool as a sqrt(token1/token0)
Q64.96 value

where tokens are arranged in ascending order of their wallet address.
I'm trying to fetch rate of two tokens in WETH:
0xc56C7A0eAA804f854B536A5F3D5f49D2EC4B12b8 (GME) 
contract: 0x05391bd57D8C6fB30d9C39F6618f2207893922dC
and
0xf94e7d0710709388bCe3161C32B4eEA56d3f91CC (DSync) 
contract: 0xBE24f9952bf2a15bc4d2661151049D9588d6c0cB
Both have 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2 (WETH) as token0, which means both prices should be “flipped”.
But for current block (19953053): 
tick of GME is -5333 
tick of DSync is 94234
this corresponds to 
(1.0001 ^ -5333) * (10 ^ -9) = 5.866814173185731e-10 for GME
and 
(1.0001 ^ 94234) * (10 ^ 0) = 12368.755591382074 for DSync
It means that one of these tokens is more expensive than ETH, because token0 they both have WETH, so to get the rate of both in WETH we need to divide 1 by the rate. But really, this is only necessary for DSync.
From this, the question is in what order the tokens are actually in the Uniswap V3 pool price.
P.S. 
To check pool price history you can use: 
https://www.geckoterminal.com/eth/pools/0x05391bd57D8C6fB30d9C39F6618f2207893922dC
https://www.geckoterminal.com/eth/pools/0xbe24f9952bf2a15bc4d2661151049d9588d6c0cb
